# Search bar is not working on Sitecore 8 rev. 150427

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I am using Sitecore search in the content tree, but the search bar is not working. When I click on the search icon in the content editor to open the search tab I get the following JavaScript error on the console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'd' of undefined
```

Since this a JavaScript error, I tried to open the search from FireFox and IE but I got the same issue.

Also I installed a clean instance from Sitecore, but I still see the same error.

[image]

Comment: Works for me on Sitecore 8.0 rev. 150223 and 150427. Force a refresh and check the Network tab to make sure everything loads correctly. Also make sure your quick search and master/core indexes have been rebuilt.

Comment: I did all of this but with no luck. Thank you

Comment: Do you have an issue only after you install the "sitecoredemo" site, or even on a completely clean install of SItecore? Suggest you raise a ticket with Sitecore Support otherwise, they are very good should be able to help you figure out the problem.

Comment: Is this a clean install of 8, or an upgrade from an earlier version?

Comment: Its a clean instance, even I tried to download sitecore root files, and I replaced sitecore files with the files that I downloaded from sitecore, but also it did not work, I think I will open a ticket with Sitecore support.

Thank you guys for the help.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue except with version 8 update 4. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Not yet, I will open a ticket for this issue

Comment: I still have this issue on my local machine, but When I copied the site files to another machine it works fine and I did not got any errors. I do not know what is the issue that I have in my machine to cause this error.

Thank you guys for the help

Answer (score 0):

Check if you got any url rewrite forcing lowercase or uppercase as the itembucket.asmx that is called is Case Sensitive. This was the culprit for me. Hope that helps.